# in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ,when turned on the machine there is no desktop icon ,no menu bars only wall paper

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, compiz, icons

when i turned on my machine i couldn't find any desktop icons or menu bars or anything just blank wallpaper background.I searched for solutions here but none of it solved my problem.

What i have tried: try to open terminal via ctrl+alt+T  but not working
then tried ctrl+alt+f1   it opened the terminal then tried as per the instruction on this.

> [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)>

in that it says to try this: sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
output is :
 compiz config not installed or something.

then i tried to upgrade from 14.04 LTS
using sudo do-release-upgrade.
it says upgaded but still not solved the problem somebody please help me out here

Comment: have you tried resetting your dconf? `mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by this:
bring up virtual console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, then type

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

it will take some time after finishing reboot the system

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: i really appreciate the help its working now.why is it happening?

Comment: its probably because you accidentally remove the unity  Ubuntu desktop .